# Loading multiple CSVs into a single pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, import

I am trying to load multiple CSVs into a single pandas dataframe.  They are all in one file, and all have the same column structure.  I have tried a few different methods from a few different threads, and all return the error 'ValueError: No objects to concatenate.'  I'm sure the problem is something dumb like my file path?  This is what I've tried:

`temps = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob(os.path.join('./Resources/temps', "*.csv"))))`

Also this:

````
path = r'./Resources/temps'                     
temps_csvs = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))     

df_for_each_csv = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in temps_csvs)
temps_df = pd.concat(df_for_each_csv, ignore_index = True)```

Thanks for any help!
````

Comment: you might be right; it's possible pandas is not seeing any file. what do you get for `df_for_each_csv`?

Comment: first off make sure when you print `temps_csvs` that there's actually a list of files in there

Comment: @sammywemmy <generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000220B47BDC48>

Comment: @Chris yeah i just fixed my file path and the list populates correctly, but now i get this error: ```ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 1394, saw 6```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be as helpful as other answers, but when I tried running your code, it work perfectly fine. The only difference that conflicted was that I changed the path to be like this:

```
temps_csvs = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "*.csv"))

df_for_each_csv = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in temps_csvs)
temps_df = pd.concat(df_for_each_csv, ignore_index = True)
```

and put the script in the same folder as to where the csv files are.

EDIT: I saw your comment about how you are having an error `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 1394, saw 6`

This means that the csv files don't have the same number of columns, here is a question that deals with a similar issue, maybe it will help :
[Reading a CSV file with irregular number of columns using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66394939/reading-a-csv-file-with-irregular-number-of-columns-using-pandas?noredirect=1#comment117379571_66394939)

Comment: you're right!  there were a few rouge data points chilling in a 6th column.  ...i feel silly.  thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Change tuple to list on the third line.
`[pd.read_csv(f) for f in temps_csvs]`

or add `tuple` to it: `tuple(pd.read_csv(f) for f in temps_csvs)`

Tuple Comprehension doesn't work this way.
See [Why is there no tuple comprehension in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940293/why-is-there-no-tuple-comprehension-in-python)